# The android game I developed opens late

Tags: unity-game-engine

The android game I developed opens late.At least 4 minutes after "MADE with unity" screen, the game screen opens.

I do not experience such a problem in empty projects.

When I add only one ui menu and vehicle model in the game, I still have the same problem.

how can i solve it?

Thanks

non

Comment: Try another device, maybe device which u are testing with is too weak

Comment: I've tried.unfortunately the result is still the same

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have anything huge inside the project, that makes it load  for so long? And have you double-checked that the code might have some sort of sleep-timer, like `WaitForSeconds`?

It would really help, if you could share some code. Also, have you tried moving the menu and one vehicle to a new project and loading that up?

Comment: I noticed that the error was caused by the 3D Models I used.I will try again using "low poly" objects Thanks.

Comment: How did the low poly objects work? Was my guess correct? :) Glad to be helping!